# How to trigger ng repeat finish event again when model value changes

Tags: html, angularjs, datatable

I have used ng-repeat finish event to trigger a function after ng-repeat finishes.
Below is the ng-repeat code

```
<tr ng-if="allAccounts.length > 0" ng-repeat="account in allAccounts" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
```

The custom directive is:

```
app.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(scope.allAccounts, function() {
                if (scope.$last === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        scope.$emit(attr.onFinishRender);
                    });
                }
           });
        }
    }
});
```

and I have called my function like this in the controller:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
      callDataTable('accountListTable');
});
```

It is working fine for me when first-time ng-repeat triggers but when I change model's value i.e. 'allAccounts', it doesn't call finish event again & tr doesn't reflect.

If anyone knows please provide me a working solution.
Thanks much!

Comment: can you reproduce your issue by adding your relevent code in a plunker?

Comment: It should work, how do you modify your ng-model and what is your angularjs version ?

Comment: I am using angular version v1.6.2. I have added custom pagination on this & not used datatable's pagination so when page changes I request again for the new data & change the model's value. After model value changes it should reinitialize the datatable with new data.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are changing to **scope.allAccounts**? If you're adding more items to **scope.allAccounts**, you can watch the length of it: **scope.$watch('allAccounts.length', function()**